# Modeling multiple choices in GAE datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datastore

The App Engine documentation gives an example of how a set of choices for a datastore entity's property can be enforced:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Pet(db.Model):
    type = db.StringProperty(required=True, choices=set(["cat", "dog", "bird"]))
```

I would like enforce a set of possible values, but allow for multiple values to be selected. I came across the `StringListProperty` property class, but I don't know to enforce a set of possible choices.

Other than clarity enforcing a schema, what I'm hoping for is to be able to modify the entities via checkboxes in the datastore admin interface. Right now, if I use `StringListProperty`, the corresponding field in the datastore admin cannot be edited. Is what I'm describing possible?

Comment: How many options do you have? You can model the entity using boolean property instead of StringProperty

Comment: @Shay Do you mean a list of booleans? Or several distinct entity properties? I have a handful of options, but that might grow over time a bit.

Comment: Distinct set of properties each is a BooleanProperty, you should be fine in the 10-12 properties range.

Comment: @Shay Fair enough, that was my initial approach. I guess I'll stick with it then. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

ndb (http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/)
will be officially available in GAE 1.6.3 (see https://plus.google.com/111042085517496880918/posts/9uJXHj8iiqV)

You could write a validator function for the property, see
http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/source/browse/ndb/model.py#112